# Effective and elegant pagination for many results

Tags: php, pagination

I wrote this function to generate pagelinks for a high count of pages and a effective navigation.
I want to optimize this code to get better round values depending on the distance to current page.
I played with $r and $c to adjust the result. $c is the adjusted centerpoint to get round values.
for exsample with current_page=1 or 1000 i get a perfect result:

```
[1] 2 3 .. 10 .. 20 .. 50 .. 100 .. 500 .. 1000 .. 1789 next
previous 1 .. 500 .. 900 .. 950 .. 980 .. 990 .. 998 999 [1000] 1001 1002 .. 1010 .. 1020 .. 1050 .. 1100 .. 1500 .. 1789 next
```

but with current_page=1350 its not perfect:

```
previous 1 .. 400 .. 900 .. 1300 .. 1330 .. 1340 .. 1348 1349 [1350] 1351 1352 .. 1360 .. 1370 .. 1400 .. 1450 .. 1500 .. 1789 next
```

the first 3 step values from current page in both directions are ok, but the values 900 and 400 are strange. 500 and 1000 would be better.
i have to adjust the range $r and the dynamic centerpoint $c better, but i can´t find a elegant solution.

please help.

```
<?
function pagination_test(){
  $page_var = "current_page";
  $cur_page = isset($_GET[$page_var]) ? $_GET[$page_var] : 1;
  $page_count = 1789; // count of pages for test
  $steps = Array(10,20,50,100,500,1000,2000,5000,10000); // steps around current page for effective navigation in many results
  $link_count = 3; // link count direct around current page
  $stepspace = ".. ";

  $pagelinks = ""; $space = $stepspace; // set output & spacer    
  if($page_count > 1 && $cur_page > 1)
    $pagelinks .= "<a href='?{$page_var}=".($cur_page-1)."'>previous</a> "; // previous page
  for($f=1; $f<=$page_count; $f++){

    // here is my problem
    $r = pow(10,strlen((string)abs($f-$cur_page)+1)-1); // get range - distance to cur-page? (10,100,1000,10000)
    $c = round($cur_page/$r)*$r; // get center point for dynamic step - snap to range

    if($cur_page==$f) $pagelinks .= "<a class=current>[{$f}]</a> "; // current page
    else if( $f == 1 || $f == $page_count || $link_count > abs($f-$cur_page) || in_array(abs($f-$c), $steps)){
      $pagelinks .= "<a href='?{$page_var}={$f}'>{$f}</a> "; // stepped & selected
      $space = $stepspace." "; //set spacer for next step
    }else{
      $pagelinks .= $space;
      $space = ""; // only one spacer behind steps
    }   
  }
  if($page_count > 1 && $cur_page < $page_count)
    $pagelinks .= "<a href='?{$page_var}=".($cur_page+1)."'>next</a>"; // next page
  return trim($pagelinks);  

}
echo pagination_test();
?>
```

Comment: Ok.... Congrats? Did you have a question?

Comment: For that many results I usually just do `<input name="page" />` and a "go" button. Let the user choose whichever page they want.

Comment: in most cases the user dont know the destination page and jump in steps. my problem is to find elegant steps for human.

Comment: if you're wasting your soul clicking through this many pages it is likely no longer a concern of yours if the page numbers aren't "perfect" - I would think a better filtration system would be higher priority than display of page steps

Comment: that´s true but this is another modul. the pagecount of 1700 is only for tests. my intention is to get the destination page as few clicks as possible with optimized steps for human. I know, more than 1000 pages is nonsense.